# What's wrong with the Java Date constructor Date(long date)?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have two objects, p4 and p5, that have a Date property.  At some points, the constructor works fine:

```
p4.setClickDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 86400000 * 4));
```

Sets the date to Sun Jul 31 11:01:39 EDT 2011

And in other situations it does not:

```
p5.setClickDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 86400000 * 70));
```

Sets the date to Fri Jul 15 04:04:26 EDT 2011

By my calculations, this should set the date back 70 days, no?

I can get around this using Calendar, but I'm curious as to why Date behaves this way.

Thanks!

Comment: It has nothing to do with `Date`, you have an overflow, `86400000 * 70` != `86400000L * 70`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's caused by an integer overflow. Integers have a maximum value of [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) which is `2147483647`. You need to explicitly specify the number to be `long` by suffixing it with `L`.

```
p5.setClickDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 86400000L * 70));
```

You can see it yourself by comparing the results of

```
System.out.println(86400000 * 70); // 1753032704
System.out.println(86400000L * 70); // 6048000000
```

#### See also:

- [Java Tutorials - Language Basics - Primitive Data Types](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 3):

the number is too big and you have overflow you should add L at the end to make it long.\8640000l (java numbers are int by default)